# C# webBroser .DocumentText возвращает исходный код только первой страницы

Tags: c#, парсер, webbrowser

Пытаюсь спарсить несколько страниц. Добавил элемент WebBrowser и кнопку, на ее нажатие поставил событие.

```
int i, p;
  string link, file, open;
  link = "http://site/page-";
  i = 2;
  p = 4;
  webBrowser1.Document.Encoding = "utf-8";
  while (i <= p)
  {
    open = link + i;
    webBrowser1.Navigate(open);
    richTextBox1.Text = open;
    file = @"D:\" + i + ".txt";
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    sw.Write(webBrowser1.DocumentText);
    sw.Close();
    i++;
  }
```

Но проблема в том, что на выходе все файлы с одинаковым содержимым, той страницы, которая была изначально передана в url.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне исправить, чтобы сохранялся код от соответствующих страниц?

Comment: Дожидайтесь загрузки страниц. Вы сейчас командуете браузеру куда то перейти и сразу парсите страницу, но она еще не открылась.

Answer (score 0):

Помогла функция на проверку

```
private void OpenUri(string uri)
{
    w.Url = new Uri(uri);
    while (w.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        Application.DoEvents(); //Выполняем другие события системы, пока страница не загрузилась 
}
```